# Curved Navigation Package rebuilds page upon tap

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am using a package in flutter called curved_navigation_bar. The only problem I have with this is that every time I tap on a button, that page is rebuilt. I am fetching some data on the home page, and have a loading spinner while my data is being fetched. However, every time I go to a different tab, then back to the home page, the data is fetched again, and so it has to load again every time I go back, hence the spinner. Is there a way I can fetch the data once only?

main.dart (I imported all other widgets from other files):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _currentIndex == 0
          ? Home()
          : _currentIndex == 1
              ? Data()
              : _currentIndex == 2 ? Precautions() : Settings(),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        height: 60,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        backgroundColor: accentColor,
        color: mainColor,
        buttonBackgroundColor: mainColor,
        items: [
          NavBarItem(Icons.home, _currentIndex == 0 ? null : 'Home'),
          NavBarItem(Icons.data_usage, _currentIndex == 1 ? null : 'Data'),
          NavBarItem(
              Icons.favorite_border, _currentIndex == 2 ? null : 'Precautions'),
          NavBarItem(Icons.settings, _currentIndex == 3 ? null : 'Settings'),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code in home.dart, that uses futurebuilder to fetch data:

```
Map<String, dynamic> local;

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchLocal() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> result;
    String url = 'api that i am using to fetch data.com';
    var responseLocal = await http.get(url);
    var convertedLocal = jsonDecode(responseLocal.body);

    result = convertedLocal[convertedLocal.length - 1];
    local = result;
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bdnavs](https://pub.dev/packages/bdnavs). It update data every time.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but I don't want the data to update every time, just the first time I launch the app.